# Including Spring Data breaks auto serialization in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I recently added Spring-data to my project and then I found that in my REST controllers, my models provided by clients were no longer being automatically serialized from JSON. How can I fix this?

I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and now the `User` param isn't having it's `String` arg constructor called and `u` is null!

```
@PostMapping()
@ResponseBody
public User createUser(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("user") User u) {

    log.info("Got user! " + u);

    users.save(u);
    Optional<User> found = users.findById(u.getEmail());
    log.info("Saved user!! ");

    return found.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build your .war *with* spring-data, run `java -jar <path-to-war> --debug` and then build it/run it without spring-data and diff the outputs, you can see that the following beans are included when spring-data is added.

```
  SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)
      - found ConfigurableWebEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration#pageableCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration#sortCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.web.config.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

This is because Spring data exposes REST controllers that link to your data repositories as mentioned here: http://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest and this breaks the default auto-configurations for serializing objects passed to REST controllers.

Simply exclude the auto configuration and your existing auto serialization will work:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```